# Scrolling to the exact end or beginning of the QListView containing QStandardItems?

Tags: qt, qt4, scrollbar, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

I have a QListView with a horizontal scroll bar in which QStandardItems are inserted. When I drag an item over the existing items the scroll bar moves as per the QModelIndex. But when i reach the end of the listview ,the scroll bar does’nt move to the exact end of the listview.There is some 3 to 4 pixels gap. The same problem appears when I scroll to beginning of the listview. How to scroll to the exact end or beginning of the listview during dragMoveEvent?

Answer (score 0):

When `autoScroll` is enabled, the view uses the `scrollTo(const QModelIndex& index, ScrollHint hint = EnsureVisible)` method to display the `QModelIndex` you are over, but it doesn't take into account the item view margin (between the items and the view frame).

You will need to reimplement `dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent* event)` to check if the hovered `QModelIndex` is the last in the row, and if it is then move the scrollbar to the appropriate end.